# Recover saved requests after crash (PAW REST client)

Tags: paw-app

Paw crashed on me today and when I reopened it all of my save requests and environments were gone.  Where is that data stored and is there any hope of recovering it?  Thanks

Comment: Hi Matthew, sorry to hear what happened :( Paw stores your data as documents (like TextEdit, Pages, or other document-based app does). You probably didn't save the file (I think the current UI is quite confusing), so data was kept using the OS X auto-restoration mechanism (which is pretty transparent). From now, please always save your files (Cmd + S). You may recover your data in "~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Autosave Information/", but I can't guarantee anything, unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! The data was overwritten.  I'll be sure to save it in the future.

Comment: Matthew, just FYI, we're working on a new UI to display properly the fact that the document is unsaved. Sorry again for loosing your work...